# Custom Social share buttons policy

Tags: facebook, twitter, google-plus

I have added custom buttons for social sharing on my website from facebook, g+ and twitter. They include follow/add to fried and like/+1/tweet. I have used the URL's available on the internet for achieving the functionality.

My question is, am i violating any license terms of these companies. Pls. review and let me know.

[Website](http://www.javaexperience.com/)

Comment: License terms in the matter of?

Comment: In matter of terms of use of g+, twitter and facebook. If you click or view source of the social share buttons on my website, you can see that it is bit customized.

Comment: _“My question is, am i violating any license terms of these companies. Pls. review”_ – wouldn’t that be mainly __your__ job? If you have specific questions, maybe then there’d be something to discuss here – but this sounds just like “please do my work for me” …

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Google+ follow button is not following the [policies for the Google+ badge](https://developers.google.com/+/plugins/badge/branding-guidelines), which says that you should not create or use buttons not provided by Google.

Sorry, don't know the answers to the other services.